# How to sort NSTableView in Swift using sortDescriptors?

Tags: cocoa, sorting, swift, nstableview

I use view-based `NSTableView` in my Cocoa app which is written in Swift, and want to implement a sort functionality on two table columns. However, in Objective-C, you can implement it by first setting the "Sort Key" in Attribute Inspector, and then implement the data source delegate method named `tableView: sortDescriptorsDidChange:`.

However, this method takes `sortDescriptor` as a parameter and lets developers use it within the method, like so:

```
- (void) tableView:( NSTableView *) tableView sortDescriptorsDidChange:( NSArray *) oldDescriptors { 
    [self.songs sortUsingDescriptors:tableView.sortDescriptors]; 
    [tableView reloadData]; 
}
```

However, in Swift Array, there are no such method as `sortUsingDescriptors`. So I first tried to convert `Array` to `NSMutableArray` in order to use the `NSMutableArray`'s method, but since my Swift Array is defined as `AnyObject[]`, it cannot be casted to `NSMutableArray`.

So how should I implement the sort functionality to the table view in Swift? I know Swift Array can use `sort` function to sort the object by comparing the two arguments and returning bool values, but is it possible to use `sortDescriptors` to sort the table? Or should I just ignore the `sortDescriptors` argument and instead write my own sort logic manually? (but then I don't know how to tell what column is clicked without the `sortDescriptors` value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best way, at least right now, is to first convert it to `NSMutableArray` and then sort it using `NSMutableArray`'s `sortUsingDescriptors` method, and finally convert it back to the original Array, like so:

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView!, sortDescriptorsDidChange oldDescriptors: [AnyObject]) {
    var songsAsMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: songs)
    songsAsNSMutableArray.sortUsingDescriptors(tableView.sortDescriptors)
    songs = songsAsNSMutableArray
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

By the way, `var songsAsMutableArray = songs as NSMutableArray` causes an error: `NSArray is not a subtype of NSMutableArray`, so I created an `NSMutableArray` instance as shown above.

Comment: I also came to that solution, but all new Swift (what a name, swiftly changing its syntax from day to day) now comes with  `*** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x.. of class '...' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead`. Trying to add this method brings even more awkward messages. Does your code still work?

Comment: Never mind. Figured it out right after commenting: Just use yourArray.sort with casing the oldDescriptors the right way.

Comment: Successfully did this in Swift 4 - slight modification that it's now "sort(using: descriptors)".  So with my array of version data stored in my "IdbVersionInfo" class, it looks like:

    `func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, sortDescriptorsDidChange oldDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]) {
        if versions != nil {
            let versionsAsNSMutable = NSMutableArray(array: versions!)
            versionsAsNSMutable.sort(using: table.sortDescriptors)
            versions = versionsAsNSMutable as? Array<IdbVersionInfo>
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }`
Works great!